Short story or novella where a man's wife dies and is brought back to life. The process is called rekindling. Rekindled people are very different
This was a short story or novella I read back in the mid 80's probably. It was published in one of the Analog-type periodicals, but I don't remember which one.
The main thing I recall is that a man's wife is brought back to life via a process called rekindling. She's been rekindled. The problem is she's nothing like her former self - she's cruel or mean and wants nothing to do with the former husband. Rekindled people have no obligation to return to their previous lives.
It's all kind of vague, but I remember that I really enjoyed this story and haven't been able to remember its title for years. I can't find it anywhere online. Ring any bells for anyone?

Robert Silverberg's very well-known novella "Born with the Dead."  See https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/449348.Born_with_the_Dead and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_with_the_Dead for confirmation.
